# Too broad [server] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Even if we will narrow [server](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) only to questions about "daemon software, which responds to queries on certain system ports", while in this question: [Software to collect information from employees over internet](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1831/software-to-collect-information-from-employees-over-internet) the tag is used in meaning "server-side software", it seems senseless to me.

I think [server](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server) tag should be removed.

Comment: Are you suggesting the tag should be removed from that question or that it should be entirely destroyed?

Comment: @Caleb entirely destroyed

Comment: I was so sure we decided it was a bad one